# Can't remove "Check out with Paypal" Button on cart? [Magento2]

Tags: magento2, paypal, mini-cart

I'm currently having the issue, that I cannot remove the `Checkout with Paypal` Button that comes from a Payment Option called `Paypal Express Checkout`.
In the Magento2 Configuration settings **I did set "Display on Product Details Page" to "NO"**, but it doesn't seem to disable it.

I did clear Cache multiple times and still does not work. I've seen multiple people having this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look:

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

```
<div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
```

This button shortcut shows in this part.
The `extra_actions` cart data comes from:

vendor/magento/module-checkout/CustomerData/Cart.php

```
public function getSectionData()
{
    ......
    'extra_actions' => $this->layout->createBlock('Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons')->toHtml(),
    ......   
}
```

Navigate to `Magento\Catalog\Block\ShortcutButtons` class, we will see a Dispatch shortcuts container event: `shortcut_buttons_container`.
The Paypal module will catch this event to add its button:

vendor/magento/module-paypal/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<event name="shortcut_buttons_container">
        <observer name="paypal_shortcuts" instance="Magento\Paypal\Observer\AddPaypalShortcutsObserver"/>
</event>
```

In this event, it will checks the Paypal Method is available or not. So, the Paypal button will not show if the payment method is disable in Admin.

> I did set "Display on Product Details Page" to "NO"

Yes, it will not affect on the minicart.

In this case, I have a suggestion for you. We can disable the `paypal_shortcuts` event, create the custom one. We can add more config for Paypal in Admin (e.g: Display on Mini Cart - Yes/No) and check this config in the custom event.

Answer (score 0):

It it can help someone, to complete Khoa's answer. In you custom module, add this file: *app/code/.../.../etc/frontend/events.xml*
With that content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="shortcut_buttons_container">
        <observer name="paypal_shortcuts" instance="Magento\Paypal\Observer\AddPaypalShortcutsObserver" disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following System -> Cache Management -> Additional Cache Managemtn -> Flush Static Files Cache. This should refresh the tempalates.

Additionally you can hide them with css

[image: Try System -> Cache Management -> Additional Cache Managemtn -> Flush Static Files Cache]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove that shortcut using **events.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="shortcut_buttons_container">
        <observer name="paypal_shortcuts" instance="Magento\Paypal\Observer\AddPaypalShortcutsObserver" disabled="true" />
    </event>
</config>
```